# Selenium interacting with authentication popup

Tags: java, selenium

I have searched for this issue, and nothing that I've seen seems to work. I am currently trying to enter a username and password into an authentication box in Chrome, and I can't find a good way to do it in Selenium. The problem comes from the fact that running the "click" method on a webelement in Selenium effectively stops all execution until the authentication box has been dealt with. I've tried three approaches:

1. Before clicking on a webelement, create a new thread. In that thread, run
   `Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());`
   Then run `alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("-ssqatest", "Sqa7-3$t"));`

The problem with this is that alertIsPresent doesn't actually work in Chrome. I can confirm this by putting a print statement right after it, and it will never run, as it throws the error "cannot determine loading status". It works in Firefox, however, which leads me to the second attempt:

2. Doing it the same way as above, but in Firefox
   This doesn't work because while the alert is detected properly, the line right after to authenticateUsing throws a selenium.Unsupportedcommandexception.
3. Directly typing in "https://username:password@url.com" into the Firefox browser after detecting the alert
   This doesn't work because I can't use Selenium to get the URL of the page, since the webdriver was instantiated on the original thread, which got stopped during the authentication popup. I would prefer not to re-instantiate a new session just to get the URL of the page.

At this point, the only other method I can think of is to use java's Robot class, but I also would prefer not to do this, as it becomes quite messy with needing to manually have the robot have a keypress and keyrelease for each character.

What would be the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to re-instantiate the thread. Unless im missing something you can go with #3 and just use `switchTo()` to change windows. Something like this:

```
    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String handle : windowHandles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        if(driver.getTitle().equals(NEW_WINDOW_TITLE)) {
          return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I first create a thread that runs after 5 seconds, then I click on the log in button and the authentication window comes up. After 5 seconds has passed, I getWindowHandles and then attempt to print out all the titles on the second thread. However, nothing prints out, most likely due to the original session instance still being stopped. It only prints out after I click "cancel" on the authentication popup.